# Symfony / Doctrine - Access service inside an entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've create an Encryption service and want to access it inside an entity.
Stn like this:

```
public function setCompanyName(string $companyName, Encryption $encryption)
{
    $this->companyName = $encryption->encrypt($companyName);
}
```

But is it possible to do it without calling this function **setCompanyName** with two parameters? Do I have to inject container and call service inside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want  to store encrypted  data in db  right ?

Best way to do this is to  create  event listener   that 'll fire up on  each entity save  , and  make  encryption there (you can inject anything you want to listener) 
and second event  listener  that fire up when loading data  from db to make decryption

If  you do this right all encrytion/decryption thing  will be transparent in code (it  will only exists in those listeners )

look at this 
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html

Comment: I got across a similar need to process the data to be set. Taking the encryption example, not performing it inside the setter defeats the purpose of the setter. Why adding a listener, when a reusable general encryption method from a service needs to be performed precisely at setter? I would say this is a conceptual limitation of Doctrine etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to inject a service inside an entity.
But you could use an entity listener to use your service and encrypt the company name juste before persisting.
Take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html

Answer (score 1):

You can inject services into your entities using a PostLoad entitiy listener. In fact, Doctrine Lazy Collections contain many services and are injected into Entities at hydration time.

However, I think this is not how Doctrine and Symfony developers imagined entities to work. And the problem is that it makes your entities very large and complex, which makes them hard to test.

The original idea of object orientation is encaplsulating data with all the logic that transforms that data, to make sure data is never transformed in a way that is not intended by the authors of the business logic code. This would make it reasonable to add all business logic as methods on your entity.

However, most Symfony applications split their business logic between entity classes and a lot of stateless services.

Even though they use object oriented terms like "class" or "constructor" for these services, this is much closer to the idea of functional programming – you could think of a stateless service as a closure, that encloses the injected dependencies. This makes stateless service much easier to test:

The results of a method of a stateless service only depends on what you put into the constructor and what you put into the parameters of the method. The order in which you call the methods however never changes what the method does.

Still, encapsulation in entities is very useful to ensure certain constraints are met. That's why most Symfony apps mix stateless services with object oriented Entity classes. But they try to keep the entity classes small and lightweight and easy to test, so they discourage depending on other services in the entities – instead, you should do it the other way around and make your services depend on the entity classes ("inversion of control").

If you really want to make sure the data is always encrypted, you have the following options:

- use a listener service that encrypts and decrypts the data on your entity when saving an loading from the database (like proposed in an earlier answer)
- create an "EncryptedData" value object, and declare it as a type-hint in your setter. The "EncryptedData" class wraps your encrypted data, and shall only be created by an encryption service, that callers have to use before setting the data on your entity
- if you use Psalm or PHPStan, you can make sure that "EncryptedData" objects are only created by that service, by adding a `@psalm-internal Path\To\EncryptionService` or `@phpstan-internal Path\To\EncryptionService` annotation above it
- if you don't use Psalm or PHPStan, you can make "EncryptedData"'s constructor private, and create a static "encrypt" method on that class that takes an encrytion services as an argument and encrypts the data and returns a new instance of itself with the encrypted data

In case of the encrypted data, the first option is probably the most reasonable one, but I wanted to provide the other options in case people have similar situations where transforming the data at persist and load time is not so reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe create a static method inside Encrypt class, and call it directly in entity?

```
class Encryption {
    public static function encrypt(string $string) {
        // your code
    }
}

public function setCompanyName(string $companyName) {
    $this->companyName = Encryption::encrypt($companyName);
}
```

Comment: could people who downvoted this explain why this is bad ?

Comment: Using services inside domain models that should be separate from such concerns is against any object oriented programming common sense. Using static methods is even worse. This way you're hacking the code to do stuff you're not supposed to. I've written entire articles on the subject. Just because you can, it doesn't mean you should. Imagine OP asking how to hammer a nail, using a screwdriver, and somebody explaining to him how to tweak the screwdriver to be able to do that.

Comment: Sometimes using a small "hack" can solve your business problems way much better then architecting the entire event listener things as other guys suggest:)

Comment: Additionally, event listeners are called on all your entity types, and each entity will pass through this listener